# OrchardCore OpenId /authorize redirects to http (instead of https)

Tags: openid-connect, orchardcms, nginx-reverse-proxy, openiddict

I'm currently running an OrchardCore CMS as OpenID Provider behind a nginx reverse proxy. I've entered the `https` URL as BaseUrl and Authority and a call to `/openid-configuration`states all correct urls (Authorization Code with PKCE).

But on signing in, I get the following response:

`GET https:.../connect/authorize` => `302 location: http://../connect/authorize?request_id=...`

`GET http://../connect/authorize?request_id=...` => `302 location: https://../connect/authorize?request_id=...`

So basically it goes from `https` to `http` to `https`. Beside this being a potential security risk, it does not work with silent_renew as it uses an iframe where the browser blocks the request (correctly) stating that mixed content is not allowed.

This seems to be related to the reverse proxy, as it works correctly when hosted without it.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 4):

Just for reference:
Orchard Core has a feature/module 'Reverse Proxy Configuration'. This allows you to enable the header `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host` forwarding which fixed my problem.